# .htaccess - redirect http to https exclude specific url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, https

How to redirect http to https exclude specific url?

```
http://www.example.com/* => https://www.example.com/*
http://www.example.com/nonssl/* => http://www.example.com/nonssl/*
```

So I make .htaccess file following this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/nonssl/
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

But when I go to `http://www.example.com/nonssl/testfunc`, it goes to `https://www.example.com/index.php/nonssl/testfunc`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is /nossl an existent dir?

Comment: no, I made this website using codeigniter. It's a controller name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this problem, I didn't find the correct way, just describe all services to redirect from http to https.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test1 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test2
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|fonts|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I know it just not recommended way. If who can fix this problem just connect me.
Thanks.