# Redirect http to https exclude specific urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37720587/htaccess-redirect-http-to-https-exclude-specific-url) question marks as solved (solution realy works!), but I don't think so
In my case `/api/.*` sould be `http`
Rule like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSA]
```

will redirect anyway and lost request URI if it beginning from `/api`

UPD:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^/(?!api).*$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^/(?!api).*$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSA]
```

give the same result =\
It feels like `RewriteCond` with exclude expression returns `true`, but if 
`%{REQUEST_URI}` is not match then it will be cleaned.

In the same time

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foo [OR]
... all pages that you have ...
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

works fine

Comment: If you already had this RewriteRule in place before adding the condition, the 301 redirect might be cached, did you test from the clean browser? (your config looks good)

Comment: @DusanBajic yes, sure. every time when i test it i change `api` on something different